FileSignature error while validating wav file
I'm using FluentValidation to validate file uploads in an ASP.NET Core application. My validator works well for most file types, but it fails for .wav files. I've added a custom Wav file format to my FileFormatInspector, but it still doesn't recognize .wav files.
Here's the relevant code:
Validator Class:
public class FilesDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<UploadFilesCommand>
{
    private static readonly string[] AllowedExtensions = { "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "pdf", "doc", "docx", "mp3", "wav" };
    private const long MaxFileSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB
    private readonly FileFormatInspector _fileInspector;

    public FilesDtoValidator()
    {
        var assembly = typeof(Wav).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        var formats = FileFormatLocator.GetFormats(assembly, true);

        _fileInspector = new FileFormatInspector(formats);

        RuleFor(file => file.Files)
            .Must(files => files.Count > 0)
            .WithMessage("You should upload at least one file");

        RuleForEach(file => file.Files)
            .Must(BeAValidFile).WithMessage("Invalid file format or size");
    }

    private bool BeAValidFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file == null) return false;

        if (file.Length > MaxFileSize)
            return false;

        using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            stream.Position = 0;
            var fileType = _fileInspector.DetermineFileFormat(stream);
            if (fileType != null && AllowedExtensions.Contains(fileType.Extension))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

Custom Wav File Format:
public class Wav : FileFormat
{
    public Wav() : base(
        new byte[] { 0x52, 0x49, 0x46, 0x46 },
        "audio/wav",
        "wav"
    )
    {
    }
}

Despite adding the Wav format, .wav files are still not being validated correctly.
Additional Context:
The validation works for other file types like .jpg, .png, .pdf, etc.
The FileFormatInspector is correctly initialized with the formats including the Wav format.
What could be the reason for the .wav files not being validated correctly, and how can I fix it?
